# Delete files which have almost identical filenames EXCEPT last word (Windows)

Tags: windows, duplicate, conditional-statements

I'm trying to sort a directory of files with some conditions but I can't for the life of me figure this out. Here's a little example of some filenames which are to be sorted out (deleted).

```
Turok 3 - Shadow of Oblivion (USA).zip
Turok 3 - Shadow of Oblivion (Europe).zip
Duke Nukem - Zero Hour (Europe).zip
Duke Nukem - Zero Hour (USA).zip
Gex 64 - Enter the Gecko (Europe).zip
NBA Jam 2000 (Europe).zip
```

I'm trying to keep one edition of each file, but there's a catch which makes this hard. In the above case I would want to keep the "Gex 64" and "NBA Jam" files because they are the only ones there. The "Turok" and "Duke Nukem" got two editions each, USA and Europe, and here I want to keep just the Europe ones.

I can't do this manually because we are talking about thousand of files. Is there a software for this, or is the command line powerful enough to have a batch file do this?

Comment: Do all the duplicate file names either end with `(USA)` or `(Europe)`?

Comment: Well no, but I can copy the (USA) and (Europe) files to another directory, this way all files will end with these tags.

Comment: So you're only interested in those ending like that?

Comment: Yes, correct. Maybe I could write a simple program in Basic, but it's been years since I used it. Would really prefer a simpler option.

Comment: All right. To sum it up: let's assume there's a lot of files, which either end with `(USA)` or `(Europe)`. Some of them share the same name, although they are targeted at a different region. Unique files should be kept no matter what, but duplicate names should be handled so that only the `(Europe)` version is preserved. Is that correct?

Comment: Well to be clear, the different region files aren't identical, but the text in front of (USA) or (Europe) is. Other than this, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Batch script

The script can handle up multiple extensions, and will default to the current directory if none is specified in the first parameter.

**Note** As-is, the script will just list the files that should be deleted, but won't actually delete them. When you're sure the list is correct, replace the `REM del /f "%%~B"` line in the `:deleteDuplicates` subroutine with `del /f "%%~B"`. Work on a copy first to ensure there are no issues.

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM ensure the target directory exists
if "%~1" == "" (
set targetDir=%~dp0
) else (
if not exist "%~1\" exit /b 2
set targetDir=%~1
)

REM set the working directory
pushd "%targetDir%"

REM set the file extensions to scan
set exts=*.zip
set preserve=^(Europe

REM initialize the name list
set nameList=%temp%\names_%random%%random%.txt

REM retrieve all file names
type nul>"%nameList%"
for /r %%G in (%exts%) do (
set name=%%~nG
set name=!name:%preserve%=$^(!
echo !name!%%~xG>>"%nameList%"
)

REM delete duplicates with similar names
call :deleteDuplicates "%nameList%"

del "%nameList%" 2>nul
popd
endlocal
echo. & pause
exit /b

:deleteDuplicates
setlocal
set tempFile=%~dp1tmp-%~nx1
sort "%~1" /o "%tempFile%"
type nul>"%~1"
set last=
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%tempFile%) do (
for /f "tokens=1 delims=$(" %%B in ('echo %%A') do (set current=%%B)
if "!current!" == "!last!" (
echo %%~A>>"%~1"
) else (
set last=!current!
))
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%~1) do (
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('"dir /b /s "%%~A" 2>nul"') do (
echo %%B
REM del /f "%%~B"
))
del "%tempFile%" 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b
```

### How it works

1. Get a list of all files matching the specified extension(s), replacing `(Europe` with `$(` in their names.
2. Sort the file list alphabetically.
3. Build a list of similar files by comparing their names.
4. List and delete the duplicates found.

### Known limitations

- The script assumes there are no parenthesis except at the end of the file name (e.g `Something (Whatever).ext`).
- Leading spaces before `(` are taken into account.
- The `$` character is reserved for sorting purposes, and it shouldn't appear in file names at all.